# BuiltValue is not a subtype of type 'BuiltRegister' error

Tags: flutter, built-value

I just learn how can i use `BuiltValue` in flutter. my implemented webservice with `Chopper` work fine before using this library.

now after changing to use `BuiltValue` i get error and i can't resolve this problem

error is:

> _InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'BuiltRegister'

my server get only `mobile_number` and this is json response structure:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "userInformation": {
    "active": 1,
    "name": "",
    "email": "aaaa@gmail.com",
    "avatar": "",
    "mobile_number": "5656565656",
    "teammate": 0,
    "experience": null,
    "age": 44,
    "gender": 0,
    "height": 555,
    "weight": 80400,
    "insurance": null,
    "job": "dddddd",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23 09:26:41",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-26 17:51:24",
    "api_token": "5QbgyBdcL"
  },
  "tickets": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "subject": "3",
      "description": "3",
      "ticket_number": 5273,
      "priority": 1,
      "section": 1,
      "solved": 0,
      "created_at": "2019-06-23 09:26:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-26 17:51:24",
      "user": {
        "active": 1,
        "name": "",
        "email": "aaaa@gmail.com",
        "avatar": "",
        "mobile_number": "5656565656",
        "teammate": 0,
        "experience": null,
        "age": 44,
        "gender": 0,
        "height": 555,
        "weight": 80400,
        "insurance": null,
        "job": "dddddd",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23 09:26:41",
        "updated_at": "2019-08-26 17:51:24",
        "api_token": "5QbgyBdcL"
      },
      "reply": [
        {
          "ticket_id": 3,
          "reply": "5050505050505050050505005",
          "created_at": "2019-06-23 09:26:41",
          "updated_at": "2019-08-26 17:51:24",
          "user": {
            "active": 1,
            "name": "",
            "email": "aaaa@gmail.com",
            "avatar": "",
            "mobile_number": "5656565656",
            "teammate": 0,
            "experience": null,
            "age": 44,
            "gender": 0,
            "height": 555,
            "weight": 80400,
            "insurance": null,
            "job": "dddddd",
            "created_at": "2019-06-23 09:26:41",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-26 17:51:24",
            "api_token": "5QbgyBdcL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": 5
}
```

i build `BuiltRegister` register with structure:

```
part 'built_register.g.dart';

abstract class BuiltRegister implements Built<BuiltRegister, BuiltRegisterBuilder> {
  //@formatter:off
  String              get mobile_number;
  @nullable String    get message;
  @nullable BuiltUser get userInformation;
  @nullable int       get status;
  @nullable BuiltList<BuiltTickets> get tickets;
  //@formatter:on

  BuiltRegister._();

  factory BuiltRegister([updates(BuiltRegisterBuilder b)]) = _$BuiltRegister;

  static Serializer<BuiltRegister> get serializer => _$builtRegisterSerializer;
}

abstract class BuiltUser implements Built<BuiltUser, BuiltUserBuilder> {
  //@formatter:off
  String           get mobile_number;
  String           get active;
  @nullable String get name;
  @nullable String get email;
  @nullable String get avatar;
  @nullable String get teammate;
  @nullable String get experience;
  @nullable String get age;
  @nullable String get gender;
  @nullable String get height;
  @nullable String get weight;
  @nullable String get insurance;
  @nullable String get job;
  String           get created_at;
  String           get updated_at;
  String           get api_token;
  //@formatter:on

  BuiltUser._();

  factory BuiltUser([updates(BuiltUserBuilder b)]) = _$BuiltUser;

  static Serializer<BuiltUser> get serializer => _$builtUserSerializer;
}

abstract class BuiltTickets implements Built<BuiltTickets, BuiltTicketsBuilder> {
  //@formatter:off
  int        get id;
  String     get subject;
  String     get description;
  int        get ticket_number;
  int        get priority;
  int        get section;
  int        get solved;
  String     get created_at;
  String     get updated_at;
  BuiltUser  get user;
  @nullable BuiltReply get reply;
  //@formatter:on

  BuiltTickets._();

  factory BuiltTickets([updates(BuiltTicketsBuilder b)]) = _$BuiltTickets;

  static Serializer<BuiltTickets> get serializer => _$builtTicketsSerializer;
}

abstract class BuiltReply implements Built<BuiltReply, BuiltReplyBuilder> {
  //@formatter:off
  int       get ticket_id;
  String    get reply;
  String    get created_at;
  String    get updated_at;
  BuiltUser get user;
  //@formatter:on

  BuiltReply._();

  factory BuiltReply([updates(BuiltReplyBuilder b)]) = _$BuiltReply;

  static Serializer<BuiltReply> get serializer => _$builtReplySerializer;
}
```

`build` command in terminal return successful and i don't have any problem, now this is my `Chopper` implementation:

```
part 'api_service.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '/api/v1')
abstract class DiabetistApiService extends ChopperService {
  @Post(path: '/register')
  Future<Response<BuiltRegister>> registerUser(@Body() BuiltRegister body);

  static DiabetistApiService create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
        baseUrl: 'http://www.example.com',
        services: [
          _$DiabetistApiService(),
        ],
        converter: BuiltValueConvert(),
        interceptors: [
          HeadersInterceptor({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
          HttpLoggingInterceptor(),
          (Response response) async {
            if (response.statusCode == 404) {
              chopperLogger.severe('404 NOT FOUND');
            }
          }
        ]);
    return _$DiabetistApiService(client);
  }
}
```

and `BuiltValueConvert` interceptor implementation for `Chopper`:

```
class BuiltValueConvert extends JsonConverter {
  @override
  Request convertRequest(Request request) {
    //@formatter:off
    return super
        .convertRequest(
                request.replace(
                    body: serializers.serializeWith(
                        serializers.serializerForType(
                            request.body.runtimeType), request.body
                    )
                )
    );
    //@formatter:on
  }

  @override
  Response<BodyType> convertResponse<BodyType, singleItemType>(Response response,) {
    final Response dynamicResponse = super.convertResponse(response);
    final BodyType customBody = _convertToCustomObject(dynamicResponse.body);

    return dynamicResponse.replace<BodyType>(body: customBody);
  }

  dynamic _convertToCustomObject<SingleItemType>(dynamic element) {
    if (element is SingleItemType) return element;

    if (element is List)
      return _deserializerListOf<SingleItemType>(element);
    else
      return _deserialize<SingleItemType>(element);
  }

  BuiltList<SingleItemType> _deserializerListOf<SingleItemType>(List dynamicList) {
    return BuiltList<SingleItemType>(
        dynamicList.map((element) => _deserialize<SingleItemType>(element))
    );
  }

  SingleItemType _deserialize<SingleItemType>(Map<String, dynamic> value) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(serializers.serializerForType(SingleItemType), value);
  }
}
```

and this is how can i want to connecting to server, send and getting result:

```
final register = BuiltRegister((b) => b..mobile_number = mobileNumber);
final response = await Provider.of<DiabetistApiService>(context).registerUser(register);
```

when i try to print response i get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!!!**

I changed

```
convertResponse<BodyType, singleItemType>
```

to

```
convertResponse<BodyType, SingleItemType>
```